# Manim Difference in NumberPlane and GraphScene Coordinates

Tags: python, animation, math, manim

I am new to manim and am enjoying it. I want to draw a graph over a NumberPlane and I used the following code

`class PlotFunctions(GraphScene):

```
CONFIG = {
    "x_min" : -10,
    "x_max" : 10.3,
    "y_min" : -1.5,
    "y_max" : 1.5,
    "graph_origin" : ORIGIN ,
    "function_color" : RED ,
    "axes_color" : GREEN,
    "x_labeled_nums" :range(-10,12,2),
}
def construct(self):
    self.setup_axes(animate=True)
    plane=NumberPlane()
    txt=TextMobject("Test")
    self.add(plane)
    self.play(Write(txt))`
```

The coordinates on NumberPlane and GraphScene seems to be in mismatch.

[Misalignment of coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hLYP.jpg)

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It's better to extend Scene class when you want to use NumberPlane.

The code will be,

```
class PlotFunctions(GraphScene):    
def construct(self):        
    plane=NumberPlane()
    txt = TextMobject("One")
    self.add(plane)
    self.play(Write(txt))
    self.wait()
```

And also it's possible to draw a graph on the NumberPlane withe GraphScene extending.
You can find some sample code for it in [here](https://infograph.tistory.com/160).